# How to create a qml object on runtime with special property

Tags: qt, qml

in qml I'm built a script that can add objects to a scene.
the object is created from a string

```
  var position // some QVector3d
  var color// some rgba
  var object = 'import QtQuick 2.2;import Qt3D.Shapes 2.0; import Qt3D 2.0; Cube {position:'+position+'; scale: 1.0; effect: Effect { color:'+color+';} }'
```

the object is created y `Qt.createQmlObject(object,view3d,'cube');`

the problem is  the `effect` property in the object string. Thats wrong with it? There's the error:
`Error: Qt.createQmlObject(): failed to create object: Unexpected token`'` Can someone help me to fix it?

Comment: Assuming the rest is correct, I think you should add quotations on the color, i.e. `Effect { color:"'+color+'";} }'`.